# Google Keyboard settings occasionally reset to defaults

Tags: security, gboard, samsung-knox

From time to time, Google Keyboard settings are reset to default with no apparent reason. It is frustrating and time consuming to set those settings again and again. Especially if you use device for multilingual communication.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Samsung [Secure Folder](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00060656/) (Knox) for some apps like mobile banking, and each time I opened Secure Folder and returned back to other non-secure-folder apps, the settings of Google Keyboard were reset. In my case selection of languages was reset to default system language, while I needed to use several different keyboards for different languages.

The solution to this was to add Google Keyboard to Secure Folder and setup the keyboard twice, on both the "normal app" list" and in the "secure folder".

To add Google Keyboard to Secure Folder:

1. Open Secure Folder
2. Click on "Add"
3. Find and check Google Keyboard on the list
4. Click add
5. Open Google Keyboard inside Secure Folder and setup the keyboard
6. Exit Secure Folder
7. Find Google Keyboard and setup the keyboar again

Hope this will help save you time, as it took me several weeks to figure this out.